# Simultaneous data transfer In Perl Chat Server?

Tags: perl, concurrency, client, chat

I am writing a Chat Server in Perl, I can Transfer messages between the Host(Server) and the Client but i can't send and receive data at the same time.

So how do I Implement The server so that it can send and receive data at the same time and not wait for one of them to finish to move on?

this is what I have written so far.

**Server**

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
use Socket;
# auto-flush on socket
$| = 1;
$data;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
LocalHost => 'localhost',
LocalPort => '4200',
Proto => 'tcp',
Listen => 5,
Reuse => 1
);                                                                  
die "cannot create socket $!\n" unless $socket;

print "server waiting for client connection on port 4200\n";

while(true)
{   

my $client_socket = $socket->accept();
my $client_address = $client_socket->peerhost();
my $client_name=gethostbyaddr($client_address, AF_INET );
my $client_port = $client_socket->peerport();
print "Connection recieved from $client_address\n";
while($client_socket != null)
{
    $client_socket->recv($data, 1024);
        print "$client_name: $data\n";
    $msg=<>;
    $client_socket->send($msg);
    }
}
$socket->close();
```

**Client**

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
$| = 1;                                               # auto-flush on socket
my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
PeerHost => '127.0.0.1',
PeerPort => '4200',
Proto => 'tcp',
);                                                    # create a connecting socket
die "cannot connect to the server $!\n" unless $socket;
print "connected to the server\n";

my $recieved;
while(true)
{       
        $input=<>;
    $socket->send($input);
    $socket->recv($msg,1024);
    print ">".$msg;
}
$socket->close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your program (scripts) are single-thread code. If you want to do a full-duplex ability you will need to do - at least - two threads per-program. One for receiving data, another for sending.

Usually three threads are used: View, Send and Receive

The first shows the data from receive queue, and sends to the send queue when something needs to be sent

Send connects or maintains a connection to the remote server and sends data out, expecting just confirmations on the data sent. Doesn't actively receive

Receive connects or maintains a connection to the remote server, and receives data waiting there, it doesn't send anything, just loops while there is data and receives it, and waits for "flags" from the sending server when there is data pending.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of threading, you can use an event framework; for example, [POE::Component::Server::IRC](http://p3rl.org/POE%3a%3aComponent%3a%3aServer%3a%3aIRC) is an IRC server based on the POE framework.